# If you were able to get rid of Hydrogen from a weather balloon as it were rising and expanding would the weather balloon rise further than usual?

Tags: atmospheric-science

I know that the weather balloon will eventually be stopped because of the atmosphere no longer being buoyant but would the balloon be able to go farther than it regularly would?

Comment: See also [EarthScience.SE] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Weather ballons are normally designed to burst at some chosen altitude so they descend and the equipment they carry can be retrieved. If the ballon doesn't burst then yes it will go higher, though as you say there is a limit. The limit is [somewhere around 50km](http://www.isas.jaxa.jp/e/special/2003/yamagami/index.shtml).

Comment: Most burst long before they reach 50 km.

Comment: @gerrit: yes, I think 20km is a more typical maximum height